# Alternative for boost ptr_array from C++ standard containers

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm restricted to use C++ stdlib and looking for same memory releasing behavior boost ptr_array. As you know this automatically release the memory for the contained pointer list.

Anyway to get the same behavior in C++11 or later containers?

Comment: `std::array<void*, N>` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any container that supports move semantics together with unique or shared pointers: `container<std::unique_ptr<T>>`. In your case, the direct equivalent is `std::array<std::unique_ptr<T>, n>`

Answer (score 2):

The newly introduced smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` are compatible with the standard containers. Use them as elements: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyType>>`.